# Android - DisplayImageOptions cacheOnDisk - How long it cache on my disk or forever?

Tags: android, kotlin, imageloader

I'm using ImageLoader and I use option ".cacheOnDick(ture)". I just need to know, how long that picture are stay in my disk? or It stay forever?

Comment: Exactly which `ImageLoader` ? most of them have caching strategy . If you does not change it it will stay forever i guess(Depends of space available) .

Comment: Wow, But we can clear it by Setting -> Application -> Our App -> Clean cache right?